# NHibernate / Localization / Lookup tables

Tags: nhibernate

I want to add localization support to my domain object. I have the following:

```
class Person
{
    int Id;
    City city;
}

class City
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

All cities are saved in a lookup db table `Cities`. I would like to have:

```
Person p = PeopleService.GetPersonById(1);
//Assert p.City.Name == 'London' if culture == 'en-us'
```

I dont like doing

```
string City::Name { get { return ILocalizationProvider.Get(typeof(City), Id); }
```

I came by this article:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx

Yet I dont know whether its supported in NH 2.1 or not.

How can I instruct NH to cache all cities in 2nd-level cache to avoid joins each time for the same locale?

Is there an easy and neat way to treat database lookup tables and localization in NHibernate ?

Answer (score 3):

In the article it says "Please note that this is no longer supported behavior in NHibernate 2.1 and up. It was a hack to begin with, and it isn't guaranteed to continue working."

So this will not work in your scenario. I would recommend this: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/localization-techniques.aspx